# java.lang.IllegalException: Ambigous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for {com.lan.exception}

Tags: java, spring-boot

in first service having a exception handler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ParentHandler extends ResponseEntityHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) {
        // Your generic exception handling logic
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

and in second service importing this dependency and extending this class as

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ChildHandler extends ParentHandler{
    
      @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) {
        // Your specific exception handling logic
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Request");
    }
}
```

for the same exception I am having two methods and tried to override the parent method error but it was showing compile error and when I execute the code getting this exception `java.lang.IllegalException: Ambigous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for {com.lan.exception}`

Comment: You are overriding the `ParentHandler`, but becuase both `ParentHandler` and `ChildHandler` are annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`, both are instantiated. If you only want the one in `ChildHandler`, you shouldn't annotate your `ParentHandler` with `@RestControllerAdvice`.

Comment: it is unnecessary that define the double  exceptionhandler in same project .   manage exception in same handler via ```ExcepetionHandler``` is compact enough

Comment: @Peng those two classes are in different projects we are using parent method in second project and want to update response body in second project for the same Exception

Comment: if there in  different project , it is more uncessary , because of  microservice design ,  we used http ,rpc or some else protocol request each other , i mean  we receive the error meesage via network ,so it always be serialized as message string  between service . if  the project both are not  services , but like common lib , so that  it is necessary to  abstract a comman handler to solve exception .  i  have no idea about your work project design , just give some exception handler design advice

Comment: back to your question , To resolve you problen, ensure that each exception is handled by only one @ExceptionHandler method. You can do this by either making the exceptions distinct or adjusting the methods to handle specific cases more precisely. Check if multiple controllers or advice are handling the same exception, as this could lead to ambiguity.